# Android InstantApp vs Full APK Permission handling issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instant-apps, android-mediaprojection

Implementing a MediaProjection sample for Screen Recording purposes while having my project setup in InstantApps mode gave me Security Permission error when running this line of code:

```
val REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION = 101
startActivityForResult(mMediaProjectionManager?.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION)
```

But prompts you and allows you to continue when not an InstantApp.

Any ideas on a workaround, besides switching back to the regular non InstantApp

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: If you're getting a security permission error on the instant app, but not on the installed app, then that means instant apps does not allow it, i.e. restricted feature. Some restrictions are listed, but not all of them @ https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html#restricted_features